# Django Date formatting in forms query

Tags: django, forms, date

Hi I have a model containing:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    recorded_on = models.DateField()
    precipitation = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I have a form which looks like this:

```
class QueryForm(forms.Form):
    precipitation = forms.BooleanField(label=ugettext_lazy('Precipitation'),)   
    startdate = forms.DateField(widget = widgets.AdminDateWidget, label=ugettext_lazy('Start Date'),)
    enddate = forms.DateField(widget = widgets.AdminDateWidget, label=ugettext_lazy('End Date'),)
```

In my views.py I have one view for the form and a separate view for collecting the data via GET. This is very simplified version of the second view.py:

```
def results(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
    ...
    startdate = request.GET.get('startdate', None)
    enddate = request.GET.get('enddate', None)
    data = MyModel.objects.filter(recorded_on__range = (startdate, enddate))
    ...
```

My date variables in GET are of the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

The problem is that the query raises this error:

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.date found
```

What is the best way to deal with my date format to make the query?

Comment: Your results view should use the form to validate the GET data. If you fetch startdate and enddate from the form's cleaned data, then Django will take care of converting to date objects, and you won't have any date format issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create Date objects from your form data, which is currently a string. The error you're getting is from django trying to compare those strings to the dates on the models.

so:

```
from datetime import datetime

format = '%d-%m-%Y' # Or whatever your date format is
st = datetime.strptime(startdate, format)
ed = datetime.strptime(enddate, format)

data = MyModel.objects.filter(recorded_on__range=(st.date(), ed.date()))
```

Should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused about the error message (i.e. where does the error occur - when you make the query?).

However, I used this to convert a string from a url parameter to a datetime.date:

```
def things_by_appointment(request, appointment_date):
    '''
    Things with appointment date yyyy-mm-dd
    '''
    try:
        as_date = datetime.datetime.strptime( appointment_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date
    except ValueError:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('%s is not a correct date' % appointment_date )


    things = Thing.objects.filter(
                              Q( appointment_date = as_date ),
    #...
```

Althoug the string is from the path and not from the query string, it should not make a difference.